# What's the syntax mean retf $12 in GAS?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, gnu-assembler

In a syscall_handler, I found the code

```
syscall_handler:
    push %ds
    pusha

    mov $KERNEL_DATA_SEGMENT, %ax
    mov %ax,%ds
    mov %esp, %ebp

    push 13*4(%ebp)
    push 12*4(%ebp)
    push 11*4(%ebp)
        
    call do_syscall

    mov %ebp, %esp

    popa
    pop %ds

    retf $12
```

I don't konw `retf $12` mean, what is the use of it? I've only seen `retf` with no immediate number

Comment: Both `ret` and `retf` can take the number of bytes to add to `esp` after the (near/far) return address has been popped. It's used in the `stdcall` calling convention, for example.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret

Comment: It's a bit unusal if you're not used to it. It doesn't mean `return 12` as in "return the value 12 to the calling function." Rather, it means "return from this function and add 12 to `%esp` afterwards." It's useful if you pushed your function arguments onto the stack before calling your function, and you don't need them anymore afterwards. It saves you the trouble of having to add to `%esp` manually after you return. If you do use it, make sure you always push that many bytes before calling.